# RDLC C# RowNumber in Decimal Points

Tags: c#, printing, reporting, rdlc

I am using "RowNumber(Nothing)" in RDLC to Print the Row Numbers in a Column. but it shows the row numbers in decimal points like 1.00, 2.00, 3.00....
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgN1V.png)

How to print simple numbers like 1,2,3,4,5....???

Comment: I think you can just adjust the number formatting of the field.

Comment: Hi Stefan.Thank you so much.. it works... :) :)

Comment: You're welcome. Have a nice day :-)